# Sanded polyurethane off

Tags: hardwood

[image]

Had a mess up on my poly with streaks so decided to redo and take back down to wood. Is it necessary to redo the sides or can I just sand down over the end and leave the rest as per picture.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would just sand the top down the edges look ok, you will want to use a fine sand paper after finished sanding and go over the edge , then when refinishing the top blend them together.